# Custom form from scratch in template

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have a paragraph that I fully themed into a contact form with the necessary  tags etc... Now my question is: How do I add the actual functionality to this? Because right now it's just plain html in a template without any logic handling the form submit.

Comment: Drupal does not work this way, your template is a dead end. You should either use core's contact form or the [Webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), and theme the individual files used/given by the module.

Comment: If you want to create forms yourself, use the [Form API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api) and [Form Render Elements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.2.x), which still means you need to design the indivdiual field and form templates.

Comment: @Hudri  Would it also be possible to maybe inject the regular contact form into the paragraph and style it from there? I assume the logic behind the form stays the same then.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to do something like this is using "Twig Tweak" module or "Bamboo Twig". Those modules provide special Twig operators to render blocks and/or forms, e.g. for Twig Tweak there is an `{{ drupal_form('Drupal\\MODULE_NAME\\Form\\FORM_CLASS_NAME') }}`

Comment: @Hudri I will give this a try! Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Build a custom module, build a custom form (with an actual submit handler), build a custom block to print that form, place that block in a disabled region of your theme, make your paragraphs reference blocks. Or make Drupal's built-in contact form a block (if there's not already one), customize that form, place it in a disabled region of your theme, and reference that block in your paragraph. Or use Twig Tweak to render the block or the contact form directly in a template. So many possible roads to take.

Comment: @leymannx Your suggestion is very good! I did use twig tweak to render the block and it works really well. Thats true, it seems like drupal has a million ways to do every little and big thing.

Comment: Consider answering your question yourself, linking the module and paste the snippet you used. Maybe it helps others in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Drupal's default contact form and customize the fields as per your need which will have all the required logic for form handling. Then you can check and apply the theme as per your need to it.

Comment: This I know, that's why I'm asking the question to do it in a custom manner because I need it for my particular use case.

Comment: The question is for Drupal 8.